# ¿Por qué primefaces no me trae la imagen desde la base de datos?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Estoy tratando de traer una imagen desde la base de datos pero no me la muestra (Solo uno de los registros tiene cargado una imagen):

[image: Esto es lo que me aparecé]

Esté es el código de la vista con el cual cargo imagenes :

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{libroController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
                      update="messages" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Este es el coódigo de la vista con el cual la muestro:

```
<p:dataTable var="libro" value="#{libroController.libros}">

            <p:column headerText="Foto">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{libroController.getFoto(libro)}" style="max-width: 200px;" 
                                rendered="#{libroController.getFoto(libro) ne null}" />
            </p:column>

</p:datatable>
```

Así la traigo desde mi bean:

```
public StreamedContent getFoto(Libro libro) {
    if (librosManager.getFoto(libro) != null)
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(librosManager.getFoto(libro)));
    else
        return null;
}
```

Y así la traigo desde mi managerBean:

```
    public byte[] getFoto(Libro libro) {
    try {
        return (byte[]) em.createQuery("SELECT l.foto FROM Libro l WHERE l = :libro").setParameter("libro", libro).getSingleResult();
    } catch(NoResultException e){
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al traer la imagen " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Cabe destacar que ésto no me manda ningún error desde consola, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: El StreamedContent en que scope esta?

Comment: Está como SessionScoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues resulta que la vista no puede obtener y enviar tan fácilmente datos del controlador (no entiendo exactamente el por qué) por eso mi función getFoto() no devuelve lo que la vista realmente espera, sea como sea, la forma correcta de traer imágenes desde una tabla en la vista es la siguiente.

Vista:

```
            <p:column headerText="Foto">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{libroController.image}" rendered="#{libroController.getFotoPerfil(libro) ne null}" style="max-width: 200px;">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{libro.id}" />
                </p:graphicImage> 
            </p:column>
```

Bean:

```
    public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    else {
        String id = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
        if (librosManager.getFotoPerfil(Long.parseLong(id)) != null)
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(librosManager.getFoto(Long.parseLong(id))), "image/png");
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

ManagerBean:

```
public byte[] getFoto(long id) {
    try {
        return (byte[]) em.createQuery("SELECT l.foto FROM Libro l WHERE l.id = :id").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al traer la imagen " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```